# Installing WinUSB and libusb at the same time

Tags: windows, libusb, winusb

After installing WinUSB (so that I could play around with libusb), whenever i plug an usb flash drive into the PC usb port, windows no longer recognizes it and doesnt put a new drive letter in file explorer.

So it seems if I have WinUsb driver installed, libusb works, but windows file explorer doesnt.

Is there a way I can have both libusb able to work with mass storage, and also have windows see the usb drive like it normally does?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no way to achieve this in Windows. You have to use different kernel drivers for Mass Storage and libusb, so you have to change the driver everytime you want to use the other one.
Of course you should install WinUSB only for the devices you want to use with libusb.